# Need to add single object to array that I initialized in React (TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am learning how to use fetch in React and right now I am trying to pull data from a [rest API](https://icanhazdadjoke.com/api).  The joke itself is a single object in JSON.

```
{
  "id": "R7UfaahVfFd",
  "joke": "My dog used to chase people on a bike a lot. It got so bad I had to take his bike away.",
  "status": 200
}
```

I believe that the reason I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

is because there is no array for me to map through. I know I need to add the joke to the array (jokes) that I initialize, but I am struggling.  I thought I was doing it with what I have below, but obviously it is not working. Can somebody help me out and explain what exactly I was doing wrong?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class JokesApi extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            jokes: [],
        };
    }

componentDidMount(){
    fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://icanhazdadjoke.com/', {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'appliction/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({ jokes: data.jokes}))
}

    render () {
      var jokes;
        return (
            <ul>
                {jokes.map(joke => 
                  <div key={joke.id}>
                     <p>{jokes.joke}</p>
                  </div>    
                )}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

export default JokesApi;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the api response, there is no field called jokes. Instead api just returns an object with a key joke in it. You need to push the new joke obtained from the api to your state i.e. `jokes`

```js
componentDidMount(){
        fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://icanhazdadjoke.com/', {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'appliction/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => this.setState(prev => ({jokes: prev.jokes.concat(data.joke)})))
    }
```